# Not getting all sources and media from GA4 report using BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, google-analytics, report

I am trying to get from GA report information on source (google, website, maps, etc.) and medium (the way it was accesed) from GA report using BigQuery. The problem is that I am not getting complete result and some rows are missing eventhough they are in the GA report, it is not showing up after using BigQuery.

The "medium" should contain 1 of 4 values (organic, cpc, cpm, referral), however it seems like value "cpm" is not delivered (other 3 are).

Do you have any clue what this is about? I was not able to find anything on the web, since the query seems to be working only 1 value causes a problem.

The data I am having exported from query looks like this (on first two rows are missing source and medium values):

```
Date        User ID                 source       medium   
11.3.2023   188536442.1673454440                              
11.3.2023   1816396854.1675008215                              
11.3.2023   1471121509.1664038139   ecomailapp   referral      
11.3.2023   108673989.1678572033    google        organic      
11.3.2023   222822601.1678572232    web          referral      

However I am expecting the value to be filled, since GA report shows the values properly as folows and all values in GA report are filled like here: 

Date        event_name      event_params.key    event_params.value
20230311    page_view       medium              referral
20230311    page_view       medium              organic
20230311    user_engagement medium              referral
20230311    page_view       medium              organic
20230311    user_engagement medium              cpc
20230311    page_view       source              google
20230311    user_engagement source              orea.cz
20230311    page_view       source              facebook
20230311    page_view       source              lm.facebook.com
20230311    scroll          source              lm.facebook.com
20230311    page_view       source              seznam
```

I have this query now:

```
 select
      parse_date('%Y%m%d',event_date) as event_date,
      user_pseudo_id,
      MAX(IF(key='source', event_params.value.string_value, NULL)) as source,
      MAX(IF(key='medium', event_params.value.string_value, NULL)) as medium,
      MAX(IF(key='ga_session_id', event_params.value.int_value, NULL)) as session_id
    from `instinct-warehouse.analytics_325608441.events_intraday_*` purchase,
    unnest(event_params) as event_params
    where 
      regexp_extract(_table_suffix, r'[0-9]+') between
        format_date('%Y%m%d',date_sub(current_date(), interval 60 day))
        and format_date('%Y%m%d', current_date())
      and key in ('source','medium', 'ga_session_id')
    group by
    parse_date('%Y%m%d',event_date) ,
    user_pseudo_id`
```

Thank you very much for any help, Veronika

I have tried to modify query based on recommendations online, however since the query seems to be working and only 1 value is a problem, it was not much of a help.

Comment: Please update your question with sample data (as editable text) that illustrates the various use cases and the issue you are facing